# Vlookup with sun tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to calculate "points" for each row based by **Category** and **Listings**

[image]

and I can fetch data from this table below.

[image]

For example, the first row is:

**Category:** Hardlines

**Listings:** 165

the outcome for the "points" columns should be 
-> **Points:** 2

Do you know how to do it in excel?
I **can't** change the structure of the source table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a formula like this one:

```
=INDEX(B:D,MATCH(H2,A:A,0)+2,MATCH(G2,INDEX(--(LEFT(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(H2,A:A,0)+1,0),FIND("-",INDEX(B:D,MATCH(H2,A:A,0)+1,0))-1)),)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, normalize your reference table. It is easier to do this when you don't have to reference from range of values (1-19).

```
Hardlines   Tier 0  | 150   | 2
Hardlines   Tier 1  | 20    | 1
Hardlines   Tier 2  | 1     | 0.5
Softlines   Tier 0  | 100   | 2
Softlines   Tier 1  | 20    | 1
Softlines   Tier 2  | 1     | 0.5
Media       Tier 0  | 500   | 2
Media       Tier 1  | 20    | 1
Media       Tier 2  | 1     | 0.5
```

Please note that the ranges of value is sorted **DESCENDING** (150 > 20 > 1)

After that, insert this formula into your Points column.

```
=INDEX($N$1:$N$9, MATCH(1, (B1 >= $M$1:$M$9) * (C1 = $K$1:$K$9), 0))
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the array formula.

[image: Sample data]

The formula is looking for `Points` referenced in column N, which matching two criteria :

1. `B1 >= $M$1:$M$9` The value on lookup is higher than the referenced values in column M.
2. `C1 = $K$1:$K$9` The value on lookup is matching the referenced string in column K.

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately I can't change the structure of the source table

Comment: @user1028100 you don't have to change the structure, but instead create  a helper table to help you simplify the formula. See my screenshot, the source table still exist, but there is additional helper table to simplify the formula used